# Make Systemd attempt to restart once

Tags: systemd, services, restart

I have an issue where every time I boot The RF Kill Switch service fails. I have looked around for a solution to this problem, but right now the solution is pretty much just deal with it. So to fix this issue I am trying to make a change to the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-rfkill.service`. What I want to do is make it restart once after a certain interval. The reason I don't want to use the Restart=Always flag here is that this is just a problem on boot, but after restarting the service I don't have issues, and if I were to have issues after boot I would like to know about them. I had originally just tried making a change to `/etc/rc.local`, but I would prefer to just handle it in the service. If anyone has any ideas that would be appreciated.

Comment: After rfkill.service starts, how long should it wait before restarting? You say "I would like to know (if I were to have issues after boot)" -- do you want some sort of notification at or of the service restart, or should it just restart?

Comment: I just gave it a delay of 180 seconds and that was working. This issue always happens when reboot the computer and I don't care about that, but if there was an actual issue with it I would want to know, such as it going down after the initial restart. This would mean that there was an actual problem with the service and I would like it to stay failed so that it would be noticed because I am not constantly checking logs and wouldn't notice unless I just did a check